# Passing data from sybase to Microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I have a requirement which needs me to write code for a data passer that would do pass data from sybase to mysql. I really don't have much experience in this field but would love to try it out. When i googled i found many articles on data migration from sybase to microsoft sql server, but that is not what i need. I need to be able to pass data from the sybase server to microsoft sql server every night for further data manipulation. There are two sites one which uses sybase and the other one uses microsoft sql, we can't do a db migration from sybase to microsoft sql as the application running at that site depends on it. Therefore the only way is to pass data from sybase to sql. So it would be very helpful if someone could shed some light on this.
Thanks in advance for whatever suggestion that you have.. :)

Comment: "Parse" or "Pass"? I think you're mixing up the two.

Comment: I am really sorry, it is pass.

Comment: Can you link your sybase server to sql server? If yes, then you can use usual queries afterwards.

Comment: Look into developing an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) process. SSIS is a tool that's part of the SQL Server platform and it will help you do just that.

Comment: Arvo: should i be looking into this http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/creating-linked-server-to-sybase-from-sql-server/ to have a link between the different databases ?

Comment: You can also use Sybase ASE CIS to link to Sqlserver

Comment: have a look at sybase replication server. this product allows you to send data from ASE to any other DBMS. it may requires you to buy some licenses and also a MS SQL provider license but it is worth looking at it. it will constantly sync the data instead of doing it nightly.